# Creating an empty folder on Dropbox with Python. Is there a simpler way?

Tags: python-3.x, dropbox, dropbox-api

Here's my sample code which works:

```
import os, io, dropbox

def createFolder(dropboxBaseFolder, newFolder):
    # creating a temp dummy destination file path
    dummyFileTo = dropboxBaseFolder + newFolder + '/' + 'temp.bin'

    # creating a virtual in-memory binary file
    f = io.BytesIO(b"\x00")

    # uploading the dummy file in order to cause creation of the containing folder        
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(), dummyFileTo)
    
    # now that the folder is created, delete the dummy file    
    dbx.files_delete_v2(dummyFileTo)

accessToken = '....'
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(accessToken)

dropboxBaseDir = '/test_dropbox'
dropboxNewSubDir = '/new_empty_sub_dir'

createFolder(dropboxBaseDir, dropboxNewSubDir)
```

But is there a more efficient/simpler way to do the task ?

Comment: Is this what you need? https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_create_folder_v2

Comment: `files_create_folder_v2()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Ronald mentioned in the comments, you can use [the `files_create_folder_v2` method](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_create_folder_v2) to create a new folder.

That would look like this, modifying your code:

```
import dropbox

accessToken = '....'
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(accessToken)

dropboxBaseDir = '/test_dropbox'
dropboxNewSubDir = '/new_empty_sub_dir'

res = dbx.files_create_folder_v2(dropboxBaseDir + dropboxNewSubDir)
# access the information for the newly created folder in `res`
```